# How to fry sepia?

Tags: frying, seafood

How to make sepia tender and tasty?

It seems to me that there is a great disagreement in the literature on how to achieve that. Advice varies from frying it very hot (300°C) for short times, to frying al low temperature for long times with a lot, or entirely without any oil.

Any well founded opinions on this?

Comment: Related: [How do you cook calamari / squid and avoid making it tough?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/32690/23376)

Comment: Thanks, this more or less solves my question. I am leaving this here for now as the word sepia does not appear in the original question and so I was unable to find it.