# Can you get food poisoning from calamari rings?

Tags: food-safety, seafood

I'm asking because cooking time can be hard to nail down - the quick cooking version involves cooking them for only 1-2 minutes (once thawed). It seems like such a low cooking time would be prone to error (some people sauté them instead of immersing them in oil, leading to possibly uneven cooking)

Is this type of food much lower risk of food poisoning compared to meat or other fish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get food poisoning from every kind of food.

The thing with Calamari is that if you cook them too long they become rubbery.

Nailing the proper cooking time is something that can be learned by experience.

See this thread: [How do you cook calamari / squid and avoid making it tough?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32690/how-do-you-cook-calamari-squid-and-avoid-making-it-tough)